# getting wrong position for Item clicked in grid view

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, adapter

I am using grid view and in each grid cell I am showing a camera preview, a `TextView` and a `LinearLayout`. I want that when I click on `LinearLayout` it's visibility should be gone and only `TextView` should be visible. Its working fine but sometime I am getting problem. Suppose only two cells are visible now when I clicked `LinearLayout` of cell one it should gone but instead `LinearLayout` of cell two is gone.

```
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"vikash: gridView Position position: "+position);
        final CameraItem camera = getItem(position);

        if(convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            convertView = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.camera_cell, null);
        }
        final int mlayoutPosition;
        mlayoutPosition=position;       
        final LinearLayout motionLayout = (LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.motion_details);

            final TextView name = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            motionLayout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    camera.ignoreMotionFault();
                    motionLayout.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG,"vikash: motionlayout visibility gone for position: "+mlayoutPosition);
                    name.setVisibility(TextView.VISIBLE);
                }
            });
          return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `mlayoutposition` variable inside `clicklistener` use `position` variable and make `position` variable **final** in getView method parameters :

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "vikash: gridView Position position: " + position);
    final CameraItem camera = getItem(position);

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        convertView = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.camera_cell, null);
    }
    final int mlayoutPosition;
    mlayoutPosition = position;
    final LinearLayout motionLayout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.motion_details);

    final TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
    motionLayout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            camera.ignoreMotionFault();
            motionLayout.setVisibility(TextView.GONE);
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "vikash: motionlayout visibility gone for position: " + position);
            name.setVisibility(TextView.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
    return convertView;
}
```

## OR

Just a simple line in onClickListener method:

`mlayoutPosition = position;`

```
    motionLayout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mlayoutPosition = position; // get latest position
            camera.ignoreMotionFault();
            motionLayout.setVisibility(TextView.GONE);
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "vikash: motionlayout visibility gone for position: " + position);
            name.setVisibility(TextView.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
```

Comment: mlayoutPosition is not the problem. I have added that to see only log. My problem is when I am clicking motionLayout of first cell (0 th position in grid view) visibiliy of motionLayout of 2nd cell is gone. According to logic visibiliy of motionLayout of 1st cell should gone

Answer (score 0):

try setting the visibility to LinearLayout.GONE instead of textView.Gone

Comment: LinearLayout.GONE and TextView.GONE have same value ie 8. So It's not the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the below one:-

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"vikash: gridView Position position: "+position);
       CameraItem camera = getItem(position);
        ViewHolder viewHolder=null;
        if(convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            convertView = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.camera_cell, null);
             viewHolder=new ViewHolder();
             viewHolder.motionLayout= (LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.motion_details);
             viewHolder.name = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
             convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }else{
             viewHolder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
         }
        // if you want to get position on click of that view set tag position to that view
    viewHolder.motionLayout.setTag(viewHolder);
            viewHolder.motionLayout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    camera.ignoreMotionFault();
                    ViewHolder view_holder=(ViewHolder)v.getTag();
                    view_holder.motionLayout.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);
                    view_holder.name.setVisibility(TextView.VISIBLE);
                }
            });
          return convertView;
}

public class ViewHolder{
LinearLayout motionLayout;
TextView name;
}
```

Use ViewHolder and use previous views by tag and use tag to get position of view

Comment: As I know ViewHolder pattern is used for smooth scrolling. In My case scrolling is not the problem. My problem is when I am clicking motionLayout of first cell (0 th position in grid view) visibiliy of motionLayout of 2nd cell is gone. According to logic visibiliy of motionLayout of 1st cell should gone

Comment: Try using  v.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE); instead of motionLayout.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);

Comment: or by help of viewHolder, set viewHolder as a tag of motionLayout and set set Visiblity visible or gone by that getting tag. See editted code

Comment: Ok but I would like to prefer you the ViewHolder one

Comment: motionLayout.setTag(position);
----------------
public void onClick(View v) {
                    Integer pos = (Integer)v.getTag();
                    camera.ignoreMotionFault();
                    v.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "tag position :"+pos+" position :"+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    name.setVisibility(TextView.VISIBLE);
                }

Comment: pos is returning correct value v.setVisibility(GONE) should work. But its not working :(   note: I have sitll not used ViewHolder pattern

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126696/discussion-between-vikash-kumar-verma-and-aditi).